# Found character ':' instead of field delimiter ','

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, file-format

Again I am facing an issue with loading a file into snowflake.
My file format is:

```
  TYPE = CSV
  FIELD_DELIMITER = ','
  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042'
  NULL_IF = ''
  ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE
  [ COMMENT = '<string_literal>' ]
```

Now by running the:

```
copy into trips from @citibike_trips
file_format=CSV;
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
Found character ':' instead of field delimiter ','

 File 'citibike-trips-json/2013-06-01/data_01a304b5-0601-4bbe-0045-e8030021523e_005_7_2.json.gz', line 1, character 41
  Row 1, column "TRIPS"["STARTTIME":2]
  If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.
```

I am a little confused about the file I am trying to load. Actually, I got the file from a tutorial on YouTube and in the video, it works properly. However, inside the file, there are not only CSV datasets, but also JSON, and parquet. I think this could be the problem, but I am not sure to solve it, since the command code above is having the file_format = CSV.

Answer (score 1):

Remove  FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' , recreate the file format and run the copy statement again.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to import a JSON file using a CSV file format. In most cases all you need to do is specify JSON as the file type in the COPY INTO statement.

```
FILE_FORMAT = ( { FORMAT_NAME = '[<namespace>.]<file_format_name>' |
                    TYPE = { CSV | JSON | AVRO | ORC | PARQUET | XML } [ formatTypeOptions ] } ) ]
```

You're using CSV, but it should be JSON:

```
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = JSON)
```

If you're more comfortable using a named file format, use the builder to create a named file format that's of type JSON:

[image: File Format builder]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The file is including CSV, JSON and parquet format. I think that a change from csv to json willl make things better for the json datasets, but not for the others right? Is there any way to accept all the formats in that file?

Comment: This is the URL from the stage i use: s3://snowflake-workshop-lab/citibike-trips

Comment: One more information: in the video they use AWS as Cloud for the project, but i am using Azure. Not sure, if this is making any issues.

Comment: That looks like sample staged data from Snowflake. The data may come in various formats, but you're using a CSV file format and trying to parse a JSON file: `'citibike-trips-json/2013-06-01/data_01a304b5-0601-4bbe-0045-e8030021523e_005_7_2.json.gz'`

Comment: I found the solution here! For everyone, who is still looking for the solution: The reason is as mentioned above by others the fact, that there are different types of files and only csv is allowed. To make sure the copy command is running and ignores the other file types you need to add one line to your copy command, which is the following: "ON_ERROR = CONTINUE".

Answer (score 0):

I found a thread in the Snowflake Community forum that explains what I think you might have been facing.  There are now three different kinds of files in the stage - CSV, parquet, and JSON.  The copy process given in the tutorial expects there to be only CSV.  You can use this syntax to exclude non-CSV files from the copy:

```
copy into trips from @citibike_trips
on_error = skip_file
pattern = '.*\.csv\.gz$'
file_format = csv;
```

Using the PATTERN option with a regular expression you can filter only the csv files to be loaded.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/feed/0D53r0000AVKgxuCQD

And if you also run into an error related to timestamps, you will want to set this file format before you do the copy:

```
  create or replace file format
  citibike.public.csv
  type = 'csv'
  field_optionally_enclosed_by = '\042'
```

[S3 to Snowflake ( loading csv data in S3 to Snowflake table throwing following error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058478/s3-to-snowflake-loading-csv-data-in-s3-to-snowflake-table-throwing-following-e?rq=1)